# Any regressors in sklearn to deal with separated weights?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

Is there anyway to seek help from sklearn if the objective function I want to optimize is somehow similar to the ridge problem but

1. the weights, originally simply `W` are separated into 2 subweights `U, V` s.t. `W = U dot V` and
2. the same constraint is on both subweights?

Just like the expressions I attached below. Thanks in advance.

[image: ridge but weight are separated]

Comment: This is not a linear regression model as coefficients are quadratic. There is probably no closed-form solution, yet you can use optimizers to find minima (e.g. [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html))

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent (up to choosing a different lambda) to ordinary ridge regression.

Let `w_i = u_i v_i`. For fixed `W`, the squared-error term is fixed, and to minimize the penalty term you end up with `u_i, v_i = +- sqrt(w_i)`. Then the penalty term is `2 lambda sum(w_i^2)`, and so we're down to ridge with `lambda' = 2 lambda`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint about finding u_i, v_i given fixed w_i. Shouldn't the solution be the same as the lasso problem? I tried to simplify the sum of the lambda terms and it gives me the 1-norm of the original weight vector.

Comment: Also what if some w_i I found using sklearn's lasso_path is negative?